# crash ao limpar app da memoria

Tags: android

estou porgramando para android faz uns 3meses, ainda estou com algumas dificuldades, tenho um app que faz um requisicao(service) online usando o firebase do google, e valida uma data em string de acordo com a validacao, ele cria uma notificacao para o usuario.
A principio tudo funciona bem... mas se eu limpar o app da memoria do celular, e esperar uns minutos ele para de funcionar, nao consigo ver que erro é, pois se eu tiro da memoria do emulador, os erros nao aparecem mais no lobby do android studio para mim.
Eu percebi em meu celular pessoal, que o servico nao para de rodar ate dar pau... mas quando eu limpo o app da memoria, se observar nos processos, ele aparece como "REINICIANDO" e logo apos sumir o reiniciando, ele para de funcionar, faz isso 2x e dai o servico para de rodar tambem.

Este é o codigo do service... que inicia tambem com boot do celular, ou quando o usuario solicita no app usar o servico, coloquei validacoes para nao iniciar ele se ja estiver rodando (creio que esta tudo certo qunato a isso)

```
 public class ShowNotificationService extends Service {

    public static AlarmManager alarmManager;
    public static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.util.Date hora = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println("####################"+hora);
        boolean alarmeAtivo = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 22222222, new Intent(this, CriarNotificacao.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);

        if(alarmeAtivo){
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> TRUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUE");
            AgendarNotificacao(hora, 22222222, "NOVAS", "hora: "+cal.getTime());
        }else{
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> FAAAAAAAAAAAAALSE");

        }

    }




    public void AgendarNotificacao(java.util.Date data, int id, String titulo, String conteudo) {

        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------AGENDAR NOTIFICACAO");
        // Obtém um novo calendário e define a data para a data da notificação
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(data);

        // Obtém um alarm manager
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Prepare the intent which should be launched at the date
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CriarNotificacao.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));
        intent.putExtra("titulo", titulo);
        intent.putExtra("conteudo", conteudo);

        // Obtém o pending intent
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Regista o alerta no sistema.
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1800000, pendingIntent);

    }


}
```

aqui esta a parte que valida a data online no firebase...

```
 public class CriarNotificacao extends BroadcastReceiver {

    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
     //DateFormat f2 = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, brasil);
     Date dateAtual = new Date();
     Date dataNotificacao= new Date();


    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent paramIntent) {

        Firebase firebase = LibraryClass.getFirebase().child("notificacao/");

        firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot tasksSnapshot) {


                try {
                    dataNotificacao = dateformat.parse(tasksSnapshot.child("tempo").getValue().toString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Problema: "+e+"         "+dataNotificacao,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("ERROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"+e+"         "+dataNotificacao);
                }

                dataNotificacao = new Date(dataNotificacao.getTime() + 30 * 60 * 1000);

                int diferenca = dateAtual.compareTo(dataNotificacao);
                if (diferenca<0){
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------CRIAR NOTIFICACAO");

                    Bundle extras = paramIntent.getExtras();

                    int id = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("id"));
                    String titulo = extras.getString("titulo");
                    String conteudo = extras.getString("conteudo");

                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setContentTitle(titulo)
                            .setContentText(tasksSnapshot.child("msg").getValue().toString())
                            .setAutoCancel(true);

                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

                    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_merc);

                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);


                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                    0,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                            );

                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(500);

                    mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Falhou: " + firebaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



        }

}
```

Comment: parece que ao limpar da memoria da erro nesta parte
CriarNotificacao.clas...
Firebase firebase = LibraryClass.getFirebase().child("notificacao/");

existe alguma limitacao para solicitacao de internet oou algo assim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O meu problema era exatamente nesta linha:

```
Firebase firebase = LibraryClass.getFirebase().child("notificacao/");
```

**LibraryClass**
é uma classe que eu acessava diretamente, para devolver a conexao do firebase... nao entendi muito bem porque nao funciona, mas...
para resolver, criei um controller, que devolve a informação contida no sqlite, onde eu havia ja salvo, para outra rotina, mas assim resolveu meu problema.